# "Element {}CcEmails invalid at this location in type WorkflowAlert"

Tags: tooling-api

I'm trying to update the ccEmails field on WorkflowAlert table through tooling API, but I keep getting this error:

```
{
"message": "Element {}CcEmails invalid at this location in type WorkflowAlert",
"errorCode": "XML_PARSER_ERROR"
}
```

This is my payload:

```
{

   "Metadata": {
   "CcEmails" :  "test@mail.com",
   "description": "Send Contact Created Directly Email to Admin"
    }
}
```

Endpoint:

```
/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowAlert/{ID}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Metadata` is a sibling property to `CcEmails` not a containing property - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowalert.htm?search_text=workflowalert

Comment: While I haven't been able to update a workflow alert, but seems changing to `ccEmails` helps get past the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CcEmails` is an array. The documentation here is wrong to mention it as [string](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowalert.htm?search_text=WorkflowAlert) . I did a get on that workflow alert and saw `CcEmails` as an array.

You have to use PATCH command to update the WorklowAlert.

```
{

  "Metadata" : {
    "ccEmails" : ["pjdev@gmail.com" ],
    "description" : "Integration",
    "template" : "unfiled$public/Integration_Error",
    "senderType" : "CurrentUser"


  },
  "FullName" : "Integration_Information__c.Integration"
}
```

Note: in JSON you have to include, description,template ,senderType and FullName, else it doesn't allow you to update.

Also provide the existing value of Recipients from GET, else it would just clear them out.

Comment: +1. I also observed that `ccEmails` was case sensitive.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thank you!